# guide on how to kick start template based flash website?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, cd-rom

I'm very new to flash and as3 design patterns. But I can read and write as3 quite ok, i've created small widgets with that. I've developed several web sites using php and also python.

Now for a educational cd-rom project i'm working on, i've basically designed all templates (A home page, a generic page with navigation and a sidebar - kind of like a wordpress blog). I have all the data for the cdrom on word files, which i intend to place on xml files.

My question is what is the best way to start a project like this? Can anyone guide me to a template or something that can be used for kickstarting this? kind of like a wordpress (without the admin)? Or am i on this all wrong? Can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

The [Gaia Framework](http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/) may be useful to you for this project.